# GraphicsMagick: Annotate text on new image C

Tags: c, graphicsmagick

I would like to write a text on an blank image using GraphicsMagick C API (low level).
Here's my code.

```
   ExceptionInfo exception;
  InitializeMagick(0);
  GetExceptionInfo(&exception);

  ImageInfo *image_info;
  Image* img;
  image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo*) NULL);

  strcpy(image_info->filename, "test.jpg");

  img = AllocateImage(image_info);
  img->columns = 200;
  img->rows = 200;
  img->x_resolution = 100;
  img->y_resolution = 100;

  DrawContext dr = DrawAllocateContext(NULL, img); 
  DrawAnnotation(dr, 1,1, (const unsigned char*)("hello world"));
  WriteImage(image_info, img);
  return "";
```

The image is created but the size is zero.
I don't understand how to initalize all these structures.
Thank you